# why design to iee754

Tags: java, c

Why high-level programming language (e.g. Java, c) the Floating-Point types are designed to float or double (IEEE 754)? Float and double will lead to numerical approximation, which causes the loss of precision (e.g., 0.3 - 0.2 = 0.099999), but in real life, the use of the decimal programming than the Floating-Point operations.

Comment: If you need 0.1/0.01 with perfect precision, you should probably be using fixed-point precision rather than floating-point (certainly if you're handling money)

Comment: In c99 one can also enter floating point values in base 16, which mitigates one source of error. Still most natural and mathematical constants are represented in base 10 in textbooks.

Comment: I don't think real life means anything.  If you want to use floating point arithmetic use it.  If not then don't.  There is no real life vs fake life here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Current high-level languages use IEEE754 floating point numbers, because most current hardware (e.g. [x86-64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64), [ARM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture), [PowerPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerPC) ...) have built-in (and wired-in) support and circuits for [IEEE-754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point). Switching to some other [floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) representation would be extremely expansive performance-wise (perhaps 10 times slower, since every operation should be simulated by software).
Also, the IEEE floating point standard was quite carefully designed and crafted (and represent a real progress w.r.t. to previous floating point representations, like on [IBM mainframes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Floating_Point_Architecture)...)

And switching to a base 10 (or some other base) representation won't help much. You'll still have the rounding issues that you are mentioning.

Maybe your application should be using [bignums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bignum). Use an existing library providing them.

The set (or [field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_%28mathematics%29)) of [real numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number) is [uncountably](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncountable_set) infinite ([Cantor diagonalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_diagonalization) argument). No matter how you do, you can't represent it exactly on finite computers. Read some math textbook....

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally all floating point operations were designed for performing mathematical calculations, hence most processor support that way. All kinds of decimal operations can be easily implemented using existing numeric operators and does not require any additional hardware support for usage.

Floating point operations need additional hardware support, as using normal methods would consume lot of processor cycles.
Hence, from early processor design specific hardware subsets were implemented to support floating point operations called floating point numerical co-processors.
They contain special registers, which stores numbers in the IEEE floating-point standard double extended precision format.

Answer (score 1):

Many years ago, a variety of floating-point formats were in more common use, including systems with bases of two, ten, and 16. For general mathematics, base two is typically more accurate and more efficient than other bases. In particular, in base two, we can always set the exponent of normal numbers to shift the leading bit of the number into the unit position (the first bit to the left of the radix point). That allows us to eliminate the bit from being explicitly stored. In other bases, the significand (fraction) field needs bits to show the leading digit.

“Nice” decimal numbers usually appear only where humans have artificially constructed them, as by dividing a unit of money into 100 parts. They generally do not appear in nature: When you precisely measure the mass of a natural object or the electric attraction of two objects, the value is not a simple decimal number. So, to support mathematics in general, decimal does not provide an advantage.

Even in human constructions, decimal is of limited use. Decimal arithmetic generally cannot exactly represent the effective unit price of an item in a but-two-get-one-free sale, the result of converting one currency to another, or compound interest rates. So, whether you use binary or decimal floating point, errors due to rounding will occur, and it is important to understand the arithmetic system and to design software to provide desired results in spite of those errors. Decimal arithmetic is not an automatic solution to the problem of performing accurate calculations.

In 1985, IEEE published the floating-point standard (IEEE 754), and this was very successful; many hardware vendors adopted it and built it into their hardware. Consequently, many programming languages adopted it as well, explicitly or simply by inheriting it from the hardware in many implementations. The 1985 IEEE 754 standard specified binary floating point. The 2008 version also specifies decimal floating point, but it is not as widely adopted.